# Loading a page from local resources does not display images

Tags: html, vb.net, image, browser

I have a WebBrowser1 control referencing webpages from *My.Resources* (local pages) and when I put the images that go along with the page in the root folder and try to load the webpage from *My.Resources* the images do not load and show a red X even though in the source of the html it has **src="rv ss 1.jpg"** for all the images.

I am using this command to load the pages.

```
If HelpMenu.SelectedNode.Name = 33 Then
    HelpContainer.DocumentText = My.Resources.Systemrequirements
End If
```

But it doesn't load the images :/